# JMeter create HTTP request body based on a previous response

Tags: java, http, rest, jmeter

I have an application that I am testing with JMeter. One of the tests calls for a REST request to be made, parse out a field from the response, and use that value as part of a new REST request. The complication is that in the second request, the XML payload needs a signature to be generated.

What I'd like to know is, is there a way to execute custom Java code in JMeter and have the resulting XML fill in the POST body of a JMeter HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **beanshell sampler or beanshell preprocessor sampler** to call java code in jmeter.

Here you can implement signature generation using java(or add library jar to jmeter runtime) and assign the generated value to a reference variable and place the reference variable in Request Body. Check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675711/how-to-use-bean-shell-sampler-in-jmeter) for more information. You can find a excellent overview  in [Blazemeter Blog](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)